Decomposition of prime $2$ in ring $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n]$
For all $n\ge 3$, is it well-know how the prime $2$ decomposes in the ring of integers $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n]$ as product of primes?
Examples for small values of $n$ show that it is either prime or product of two primes. I am curious for general situation.

Let $\varphi$ be the Euler totient function and write $n=2^km$ with $\text{gcd}(2,m)=1$. Then $2=\mathfrak{p}_1^{e}\cdots\mathfrak{p}_{r}^e$, where $e=\varphi(2^k)$, and $r=\varphi(m)/f$ where $f$ is the order of $2$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^\times$. The number $f$ also has meaning: it is the degree of the field extension $[\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n]/\mathfrak{p}_i:\mathbb{F}_2]$. This is the $p=2$ case of theorem 26 in the textbook Number Fields by Daniel Marcus.
There are two proofs of this I know of. The first uses the idea of a Frobenius element and is the one featured in Marcus' book (though without using the word Frobenius element as that is only introduced in the next chapter.) The second uses the classification of finite fields and I will sketch it here.
You consider two special cases. When $n=2^k$ and when $\text{gcd}(n,2)=1$.
In the first case, the element $1-\zeta_{2^r}\in \mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n]$ has norm $2$. This implies that $2$ is completely ramified in this extension, so in this case we have $2=\mathfrak{p}^e$ and this case holds.
In the second case. In this case, $2$ is unramified because $2$ is coprime to the discriminant of the extension. If you can compute the degree of the field extension $(\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n]/\mathfrak{p})/(\mathbb{Z}/2)$, then you can deduce the factorization of $2$ in this field. Abstractly, this is the extension $\mathbb{F}_2(\zeta_n)/\mathbb{F}_2$. By using the classification of finite fields, you can see that $\mathbb{F}_2(\zeta)_n=\mathbb{F}_{2^f}$, where $f$ is the order of $2$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times$.
If you decompose $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{2^r})$, you then deduce the general case.
